# Phone number color is changing on iPhone 6

Tags: html, css, iphone, responsive-design, responsive

I created a landing page and inserted a phone number there. It looks fine on every phone mobile I have checked, but one of the uses who used iPhone 6 complained about the phone number color changing to grey, and then blue after he clicked on it.

I tried inserting the following code:

```
}
  .phone a, .phone a:link, .phone a:visited, .phone a:hover, .phone a:active, .phone a:focus {
  /* link styles go here, e.g.: */  
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ff6600;
}
```

The HTML is:

```
<p class="phone">052-9777477</p>
```

Didn't work though.
What did I do wrong?

Thank you so much for wanting to help!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

- [`<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one good model for styling phone numbers, it's a true phone link for smartphone viewports and regular text for desktop viewports:
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/YVadmO

**HTML**

```
<a class="tel" tabIndex="-1" href="tel:1-052-977-7477">1-052-977-7477</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.tel,.tel:visited { /*for small screens */   display:block; 
  color:#fff; 
  background-color:#000; 
  padding:1em; 
  text-decoration:none; 
} 

.tel:hover,.tel:focus { 
  color:#000; 
  background-color:#fff; 
} 
@media screen and (min-width: 28.5em) { /* for larger screens */ 
  .tel,.tel:visited { 
    background:none; 
    cursor:default; 
  } 
  .tel,.tel:focus { color:#000; } 
}
```

[Credit for this code](http://geoffmuskett.com/css-styling-for-phone-numbers-on-iphone-and-ipad/)